# Jenkins: cannot automatically install gradle. No version list from Gradle.org

Tags: jenkins, gradle

in Jenkins, I have always used the option to install Gradle automatically from the Gradle.org server (Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Gradle Installations.

Now I have set up a new Jenkins installation on an Ubuntu 14 System.
I installed the Gradle plugin, but now, when I choose "Install automatically" in the Gradle configuration, I am not able to choose the Gradle version that should be downloaded. Usually you get a select box with all available Gradle versions, but in my case, I only get an empty text field under "Install from Gradle.org".

Please see the screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhBBa.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list of available Gradle versions shown in that UI is download perodically by Jenkins.
However, for Jenkins versions [older than 1.619](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27694), the list was not fetched after installing a plugin for the first time.

So if you just have the empty text field, most likely the downloading has failed, or you have an older Jenkins version.

As a workaround, you can visit Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Advanced, and click on <kbd>Check now</kbd> at the bottom of the page.  This will trigger an update of the Gradle versions.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem!

Altough, at the first try, the "Check now" button gave me the error "Signature verification failed in downloadable 'hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller'.

After a little googling I switched JDK version from 1.8 to 1.7 and then it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Check now` button did not work for me.
Nor re-installing the Gradle plugin.
I only got an empty text field under "Install from Gradle.org".
Although, changing browser from Firefox to Chrome helped.

I've lost 2 hours with this when I've finally figured this out. :)